# Magento 2: I'm unable to save new products

Tags: magento-2.1, product, database, migration, magento2-migration-tool

My website is running on Magento 2.
I have migrated data from Magento 1.x to version 2.1 using UB data migration tool.
Now I am planning to upgrade Magento 2.1.3. After Magento upgrade

I am unable to save new products. It shows error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1449 The user specified as a definer
>   ('rb_magento2'@'localhost') does not exist, query was: INSERT INTO
>   `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `type_id`,
>   `sku`, `has_options`, `required_options`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

The user **rb_magento2** is or live Magento database but I have created a copy of Magento on a new server with the different username.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10169960/2047249

Comment: Check the user has all privileges

Comment: I have provided all the privileges  but it is having different user

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I got the solution doing this:

1. Export database using the following command:

   ```
   mysqldump -h [database_host] --user=[database_username] --password=[password] --single-transaction main | sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/' | gzip > /path/to/database_name.sql.gz
   ```
2. Import the database again.

The error is caused because the user `rb_magento2` doesn't exist or doesn't have permissions.

Also you can try creating a user with name `rb_magento2` but the first solution is the most recommended.

Check this doc:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/live/stage-prod-migrate.html#troubleshooting-the-database-migration

Answer (score 0):

**1 -** You can fix that renaming the file `app/etc/env.php` to `app/etc/env.php.bkp`.

**2 -** Use the command `cat app/etc/env.php.bkp` to see the DB credentials.

**3 -** Run these commands below changing the data like DB host, user, password, base URL, admin user, password, etc..

```
php -f ./bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost/ \
    --db-host=db \
    --db-name=magento \
    --db-user=magento \
    --db-password=magento \
    --admin-firstname=Magento \
    --admin-lastname=Commerce \
    --admin-email=user@example.com \
    --admin-user=admin \
    --admin-password=admin123 \
    --language=en_US \
    --currency=USD \
    --timezone=America/Chicago \
    --use-rewrites=1 \
    --backend-frontname=admin
```

**4 -** Finalize running these commands:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

mage maintenance:enable
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/di/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
mage cache:flush &&
mage indexer:reindex &
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
mage setup:static-content:deploy
mage setup:di:compile
mage maintenance:disable
mage setup:db-schema:upgrade
mage setup:db-data:upgrade
mage setup:db:status
```

Done!